# get count collection with socket.io-mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm trying to make a simple task.
In the first place, on client side, i'm sending data to server and then i insert these data into my mongodb database.
Then i try to get count of clients from my database.

```
var express = require('express');
var MONGO_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase";
var app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
fs = require('fs');
var countUserSuscribed =0;

//here i insert data
/* Connection events */
io.on('connection', function (client) {
console.log("User connected");
    client.on('InsertNewUser', function (newUser) {
        console.log("we ar in InsertNewUser event");
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        mongo.connect(MONGO_URL, function (err, db) {
            console.log("we are connected to mongodb");
            var Users = db.collection('User');
            console.log("on crée la collection et on fait l'ajout");
            Users.insert({ player: myP }, function (err, o) {
                if (err) { console.warn(err.message); }
                else { console.log("user inserted into db: user"); }
            });
        });
    })
});

//GET COUNT USER
console.log("here we get count user");
mongo.connect(MONGO_URL, function (err, db) {
countUserSuscribed = Users.count();
console.log("we got " + countUserSuscribed + " user in mongoDB");

});
```

With this code i can create collections and insert documents but the count function doesn't work and i didn't find much explanations on npm documentation.
Is it possible to use others mongodb functions than insert and collection with socket.io-mongodb ? 
If it is, can someone give an example or explain me how to use it?

Comment: So you are just counting all the inserted records?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want to do now but not only that, i would like to be able to use all mongodb insert, create, update, delete or query functions. Is it possible with mongodb-autoincrement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count function works but is async function and takes a callback.
here's the fix:

`countUserSuscribed = Users.count(function (err,c) { console.log(c) });`

Comment: Thank you, and then by adding a callback i can also use collection.find(), .insertMany(), remove(), etc ?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-autoincrement consider using that. It keeps a track of all inserted document. Plus it has a handy feature to get the next count. Example let's say you inserted two records. If you call next count it will show 3. There fore to get the total documents inserted call get next count - 1. Make sense?

Sorry here is the correct one. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: Use mongoose auto increment

Comment: Did it accordingly sir?

Comment: Yes, it did. Is it possible to also query specific values with it?

Comment: Hmmm how specific we talking here?